# Replace text in camelCase inside the string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have string like:

```
/api/agencies/{AgencyGuid}/contacts/{ContactGuid}
```

I need to change text in `{ }` to cameCase

```
/api/agencies/{agencyGuid}/contacts/{contactGuid}
```

How can I do that? What is the best way to do that? Please help

I have no experience with Regex. So, I have tried so far:

```
string str1 = "/api/agencies/{AgencyGuid}/contacts/{ContactGuid}";

string str3 = "";
int i = 0;
while(i < str1.Length)
{
    if (str1[i] == '{')
    {
        str3 += "{" + char.ToLower(str1[i + 1]);
        i = i + 2;
    } else
    {
        str3 += str1[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with regex of course.

But you can do it also with LINQ like this:

```
var result = String.Join("/{", 
str1.Split(new string[1] { "/{" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
.Select(k => k = !k.StartsWith("/") ? Char.ToLowerInvariant(k[0]) + k.Substring(1) : k));
```

What is done here is: Splitting into 3 parts:
"/api/agencies/"
"AgencyGuid}/contactpersons"
"ContactPersonGuid}"
After that we are selecting from each element such value: "If you start with "/" it means you are the first element. If so - you should be returned without tampering. Otherwise : take first char (k[0]) change it to lowercase ( Char.ToLowerInvariant() ) and concatenate with the rest.

At the end Join those three (one unchanged and two changed) strings

With Regex you can do it as:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\/{(\w)");
var result = regex.Replace(str1, m => m.ToString().ToLower());
```

in regex we search for pattern "/{\w" meaning find "/{" and one letter (\w). This char will be taken into a group ( because of () surrounding) and after that run Regex and replace such group to m.ToString().ToLower()

Comment: Thanks. Of course +1. But it is a little bit difficult to understand what's going on here. Any other ways?

Comment: Now you have explanation and regex alternative :)

Comment: Ok, I like your case with regex. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't use regex, but since you asked

```
Regex.Replace(
  "/api/agencies/{AgencyGuid}/contactpersons/{ContactPersonGuid}", 
   @"\{[^\}]+\}", 
   m =>
     $"{{{m.Value[1].ToString().ToLower()}{m.Value.Substring(2, m.Value.Length-3)}}}", 
   RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
)
```

This assumes string interpolation in c# 6, but you can do the same thing by concatenating.

Explanation:

- `{[^}]+}` - grab all letters that follow an open mustache that are not a close mustache and then the close mustache
- `m => ...` - A lambda to run on each match
- `"{{{m.Value[1].ToString().ToLower()}{m.Value.Substring(2, m.Value.Length-3)}}}"` - return a new string by taking the an open mustache, the first letter lowercased, then the rest of the string, then a close mustache.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. What would you use?

Comment: Just something simpler probably - maybe split on path parts and check which ones are `{tokenized}`. But really I probably question the need for this at all - this looks like a routing path - most routing engines handle any capitalization just fine